# equivalent to text-anchor in regular html elements

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there any equivalent to `text-anchor` of svg's `<text>` element in another html elements (eg. div, span, ...)?

It looks now as following:

`<text dy="..." x="..." y="..." style="text-anchor: end;">text</text>`

and if I would like to have it in `div`

`<div style="text-anchor: end;">text</div>`

it doesn't work, even if I make it absolute positioned.

Comment: You can't `position` text-nodes since they are not selectable by CSS. You can only apply text-align to parent of text nodes which then aligns the text. It'd not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [`text-align: left|right|center|justify|initial|inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)? You can also use `float` or `margin: X auto` if you want to center a block element with a fixed `width`.

Here you can see different examples:

```css
body {
  font-family: Monospace;
}

div{
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  margin: .25rem 0 0 0;
  padding: .125rem;
  overflow:hidden;
}

span {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

/* center-line */

#center-line {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  width:0;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: -2px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 255, 255, .5)
}

/* text-align */

#ltext {
  text-align:left;
}

#ctext {
  text-align:center;
}

#rtext {
  text-align:right;
}


/* float */

#ltext-float > span{
  float: left;
}

#rtext-float > span{
  float: right;
}


/* margin: X auto */

#ltext-block > span, #ctext-block > span, #rtext-block > span{
  display:block;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:left;
}

#ctext-block > span{
  text-align:center;
}


#rtext-block > span{
  text-align:right;
}


/* position: absolute */

#abs-l, #abs-r, #rtl, #rtl-hack {
  height: 1rem;
}

#abs-l > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

#abs-r > span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
}


/* direction: rtl */

#rtl > span, #rtl-hack > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  direction:rtl;
  width:0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:none;
}

#rtl-hack > span >span:after{
  content:"a";
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<i id="center-line"></i>

<h3>TEXT-ALIGN</h3>

<div id="ltext">text-align: left;</div>

<div id="ctext">text-align: center;</div>

<div id="rtext">text-align: right;</div>

<h3>FLOAT</h3>

<div id="ltext-float"><span>float: left;</span></div>

<div id="rtext-float"><span>float: right;</span></div>

<h3>MARGIN: X AUTO + DISPLAY: BLOCK + TEXT-ALIGN</h3>

<div id="ltext-block"><span>margin: 0 auto; display: block; text-align: left;</span></div>

<div id="ctext-block"><span>margin: 0 auto; display: block; text-align: center;</span></div>

<div id="rtext-block"><span>margin: 0 auto; display: block; text-align: right;</span></div>

<h3>POSITION: ABSOLUTE</h3>

<div id="abs-l"><span>position: absolute; left: 50%;</span></div>

<div id="abs-r"><span>position: absolute; rigth: 50%; </span></div>

<h3>POSITION: ABSOLUTE + WIDTH: 0 + DIRECTION: RTL + WHITE-SPACE: NOWRAP</h3>

<div id="rtl"><span><span>I'm overflowing to left!</span></span></div>

<div id="rtl-hack"><span><span>With hack!</span></span></div>
```

**EDIT:**

You can position absolute-positioned elements with `left` and make the text overflow to left instead of right with `direction: rtl` (see the last example). You also need to:

- Set `width: 0` so that the text always overflows.
- Set [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to prevent text lines from breaking and not showing up.
- Add an extra element to wrap your text if you need to have a `border`, `background`, `box-shadow`...
- Moreover, some symbols at the end of the text may appear at the beginning, so you will probably need a hack to solve that. You can use the `after` pseudo-element width `font-size: 0`.

Note that **selecting text may become a pain**.

I would just try to use `right` instead of `left` on absolute-positioned elements (penultimate example) or any of the other solutions if it is possible for your use case.

Comment: It's a good idea, but it doesn't work like text-anchor. Here, to put text on right, we have to have wide div. It wouldn't work if we had text wrapped with absolute positioned div and text coming from this div should appear on the left of anchor point of absolute position.

Comment: @michalv See the last example I added. I think that's what you are asking.